# Tomcat is Not showing my Images on jsp page Dynamically from a folder

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, wampserver, dreamweaver

I Want To USe Dynamically generation of Images on My Jsp Page. Please tell me the logic to display all images stored in a folder on my jsp page.
        Tomcat is Not showing my Images on jsp page Dynamically from a folder

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us to help narrow down your problem? This site is aimed at helping you with specific programming questions, so if you can please be specific and show anything you've already done.

Comment: Please tell me in my next question, as i am new user, i'm not able to post My question's answer right now...